# Can not use socket after file transfer - C Socket

Tags: c, sockets

In here I am sending file name first then sending the file in chunks, then trying to read the received message but it is just freezing. No respond. But after loop if I shutdown the WR `shutdown(connfd,SHUT_WR);` It is working fine. Though I should be able to send message again, if I do this I can not do that.
**CLIENT.C**

```
    write(sockfd, fname,100);

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname,"rb");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File opern error");
        exit(1);   
    }   

   
    int hi = 0;
   
    while(1)
    {
        /* First read file in chunks of 256 bytes */
        unsigned char buff[1024]={0};
        int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp);
            

        /* If read was success, send data. */
        if(nread > 0)
        {
            hi++;
            //printf("Sending \n");
            write(sockfd, buff, nread);
        }
        if (nread < 1024)
        {
            if (feof(fp))
    {
        printf("File transfer completed!\n");
    }
            if (ferror(fp))
                printf("Error reading\n");
            break;
        }
      
    }
    
    char fname2[100];
    // cant read
    read(sockfd, fname2, 100);
    printf("File Name: %s\n",fname2);
```

**SERVER.C**

```
FILE *fp;
int bytesReceived = 0;
char recvBuff[1024];
char fname[100];
char fname2[100];
read(newsockfd, fname, 100);
//strcat(fname,"AK");
printf("File Name: %s\n",fname);
printf("Receiving file...");
fp = fopen(fname, "ab"); 
    if(NULL == fp)
    {
     printf("Error opening file");
    }

long double sz=1;
/* Receive data in chunks of 256 bytes */
   
    printf("\nCompleted.\n");
    int hi = 0;
   
    while((bytesReceived = read(newsockfd, recvBuff, 1024)) > 0)
 { 
     hi++;
     sz++; 
         fwrite(recvBuff, 1,bytesReceived,fp);
     }
     printf("Not pring this this!");

    if(bytesReceived < 0)
     {
        printf("\n Read Error \n");
     }
    
     
  
     write(newsockfd, "SayGee",100);
```

Comment: Please add a compiling example. And fix the indention.

Answer (score -1):

I had to send the size of the file, then check from the other side inside loop. It was in deadlock.I found the solution. So thanks anyway!